# R: Converting a string to useful date and time values

Tags: r

I have a csv file with a column values like `"20140929120000"` which gives the date and time.

After importing it to R, I want to format this as a date variable while keeping the time part as well(if that is possible).
So, the output should be a date variable `'2014-09-29'`.
How would I get the time part as a separate column with value `"12:00:00"`?

Comment: Please include a reproducible example of your data using ``dput(data)`` and paste it into your question. This will make it much easier for others to help you. Thanks./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
install.packages('lubridate')
library(lubridate)

y <- as.numeric(20140929120000)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(ymd_hms(y), tz= Sys.timezone()),
         Time = format(lubridate::ymd_hms(y), "%H:%M:%S")
```

just change the Y in the mutate to your date column

Comment: unfortunately that did'nt work. It gave an error "All formats failed to parse. No formats found."

Comment: I've updated the "Date" portion above; I  assume that is what is giving the error. Make sure you've loaded the Lubridate library.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `POSIXct` type here:

```r
val <- "20140929120000"
mask <- "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
as.POSIXct(strptime(val, mask))

[1] "2014-09-29 12:00:00 UTC"
```

To see the various components of the timestamp, try:

```r
unclass(strptime(val, mask))
```